# CSS3 Animation: Why doesn't animating the same property work?

Tags: animation, css, transform

I'm trying to get this animation to work in Chrome:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flipAnimation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes disappear {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.flipAnimation {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    -webkit-animation: flipAnimation .5s, appear .2s, disappear .3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, .3s, 2s;
}
```

But it's always glitchy. For one, the div.flipAnimation doesn't appear with opacity 0. Second, the div flashes in and out and the last disappear animation doesn't seem to trigger properly. Is there a problem with have 2 opacity animations in the same animation even though they're spaced with delays?

Comment: Hi I want to help can you put allso the html code or give link to jdFiddle Thanks

Comment: @yossi try this jFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AQD9h/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is the desired effect are you aiming for, but you can look up at my solution:

[**JS Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AQD9h/3/)

I think the effect you are looking for cannot be achieved with `keyframes`. Please confirm if this is satisfactory!

Comment: I'm not try to reverse the rectangle...I just want it to straighten while fading in, then, after a delay, fade out.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code working.
[Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/AQD9h/4/)
the reson that it was not work is the delay time. you could not see the different.
so I change the delay time for 10 sec just for you see that it is work.
[Your code work with other delay](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/AQD9h/6/)

I make some change in the code for to see that is work, just change the time and ather thing according your request:

first you see the appear ,flipAnimationu working togther after 20s you will see the disappear work and change color to azure,black,azure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can't be done with key frames alone. I'm going to use jquery to do the final fade out animation.